# Detecting browser language and avoiding nullreference exception

Tags: c#

I want to detect the browser language so I can switch languages when people connect to my website.
But when a user hasnt filled in the language in the browsers options I always get a null value with

```
string browserlanguage = Request.UserLanguages[0]
```

How could I avoid the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check for `Request.UserLanguages != null`.

For instance:

```
var l = Request.UserLanguages;
string browserlanguage = l ?? l[0] : "en";
// fall back to en, or set to "" or null.
```

**Edit:** (re your comment) If the above fails, too, `Request` itself was null, which afaik is impossible (could you check `Request != null` to make sure?). Did you possibly have a null reference later in your code?

Comment: Just a heads up, the ternary if statement syntax is wrong in what you posted.
Should be 

```string browerlanguage = l ? l[0] : "en";```

Answer (score 6):

```
string lang = (Request.UserLanguages ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>()).FirstOrDefault();
```